# Mirror драйвера

Tags: c++, драйвер

Задача состоит в получении изменённых областей экрана с большой скоростью.
Насколько известно мне, для этого используются mirror драйвера.
Стоит ли связываться с этой технологией и, если нет, какие альтернативы вы могли бы предложить?

В драйверах я достаточно не разбираюсь, и, конечно, краткое описание принципов работы такого драйвера мне бы пригодилось.

Если есть те, у кого уже был опыт написания таких драйверов, поделитесь пожалуйста проблемами, с которыми вы столкнулись и их решениями.

Answer (score 1):

mirror драйвера использовались для этих целей до Windows8. С выходом Windows8 им на смену пришел [Desktop Duplication API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx). Он позволяет осуществлять захват экрана полностью или только модифицированных областей с использованием аппаратного ускорения.

Comment: Я в курсе на счёт этого способа. Он мне не подходит. 14 мл на получение изменённых областей + 30-70 мл на преобразование ID3DTexture2D в BITMAP это много.

Comment: Да и потом, нужно учитывать масштабирование. Это не возможно с DeskDuplAPI (..достаточно быстро организовать).

Comment: А вот драйвер и масштаб в аккурат подгонит, и чистый BITMAP выдаст, и мышку зафиксирует на всём этом.

Comment: мл - *мс ......